# paginate_alphabetically gem: Pagination links in namespace not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, pagination, routes

I have an admin namespace in a rails 3.2 app. I want to paginate a postgres database of authors, using the paginate_alphabetically gem at https://github.com/edendevelopment/paginate_alphabetically .

The controller in app/controllers/admin (class Admin::AuthorsController < AdminController ) has:

```
def index
    @authors = Author.includes(:stories).alphabetical_group(params[:letter])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @authors }
    end
end
```

The author.rb model in app/models has:
paginate_alphabetically :by => :last_name

And the authors view in app/views/admin/index.html.erb has:

```
<ul class='pagination'>
<%- Author.pagination_letters.each do |letter| -%>
<li><%= link_to(letter, admin_authors_path(:letter => letter)) %></li>
<%- end -%>
</ul>
```

This seems to be generating the correct html, with:

```
<ul class='pagination'>
<li><a href="/admin/authors?letter=A">A</a></li> 
...etc.
</ul>
```

But the links don't go anywhere when clicked. The ruby output says the following:

```
Started GET "/admin/authors?letter=A" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-14 18:18:15 -0400
Processing by Admin::AuthorsController#index as JS
Parameters: {"letter"=>"A", "collection"=>{"list"=>:get}}
Author Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" 
Author Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE (LOWER(last_name) LIKE     
'a%') ORDER BY last_name
Story Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "stories".* FROM "stories" INNER JOIN "authors_stories" ON   
"stories"."id" = "authors_stories"."story_id" WHERE "authors_stories"."author_id" = 1
Story Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "stories".* FROM "stories" INNER JOIN "authors_stories" ON "stories"."id" = "authors_stories"."story_id" WHERE "authors_stories"."author_id" = 2
 Story Load (67.1ms)  SELECT "stories".* FROM "stories" INNER JOIN "authors_stories" ON "stories"."id" = "authors_stories"."story_id" WHERE "authors_stories"."author_id" = 3
 Story Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "stories".* FROM "stories" INNER JOIN "authors_stories" ON "stories"."id" = "authors_stories"."story_id" WHERE "authors_stories"."author_id" = 4
 Story Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "stories".* FROM "stories" INNER JOIN "authors_stories" ON "stories"."id" = "authors_stories"."story_id" WHERE "authors_stories"."author_id" = 5
 Rendered admin/authors/_authors.html.erb (131.6ms)
 Rendered admin/authors/index.html.erb within layouts/admin (149.5ms)
```

Completed 200 OK in 171ms (Views: 96.4ms | ActiveRecord: 73.3ms)

When I physically enter the url localhost:3000/admin/authors?letter=A (or any other letter), I get a page with what I want, a list of alphabetized authors depending on the letter. It just doesn't work with the above mentioned links.

In my routes.rb file I have:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :authors
  resources :issues
  resources :stories  
  root :to => 'authors#index
end
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Working on figuring out what's causing your problem, but I'm about half way through and I need to stop and tell you to fix your N+1 queries problem before it grows to something bigger. In authors#index, add .includes(:stories) to your query...

Comment: Thanks for that @sgrif. I'm sort of new to rails. Just changed authors#index and edited this post to reflect the change.